# How to resolve “Element not visible” error shows for only one element in the popup.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, selenium

**All the attributes in same form but script reach to last element shows "element not visible error"**

All the elements in same level div tags but script runs the click event (Signup Button) shows Error message “element not visible”. However except submit button click, all the other fields i can populate data in the it and able run the click  event also,  works in popup window. problem i have popup i added screenshot image.

**HTML code here** –

```
<form id="sighUpForm" class="form-signin ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern" novalidate="" name="sighUpForm">
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="ng-bind-htmling" ng-bind-html="translation.signup_mobile">Mobile No.</label>
<div class="input-group">
<span class="error-msg ng-hide" style="color:red" ng-show="sighUpForm.PhoneNo.$invalid && submitted">
</div>
<div style="text-align:center;">
<label class="checkbox-inline ng-bind-htmling" style="line-height:1.8; font-size:12px">
<input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" type="checkbox" value="" ng-model="user.termAndCondition" required="" name="termAndcondition" style="height:15px; width:15px; margin-top:5px; margin-right:3px "/>
I agree to the 
<a data-target="#tandcmodal" data-toggle="modal" href="#">
 and 
<a data-target="#ppmodal" data-toggle="modal" href="#">
</label>
<br/>
</div>
<div class="text-center">
<!-- <small class="tc-text">By signing up, you agree to our <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tandcmodal">Terms &amp; Condions</a> and <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ppmodal">Privacy Policy</a></small><br />-->
<!--<button id="submitSignup" type="submit" ng-click="SignUpUser()" class="button signup-btn">Signup</button>-->
<a id="submitSignup" class="button signup-btn" ng-click="SignUpUser()">
</div>
</form>
```

**Selenium Code Here :-**

```
//Enter PhoneNumber
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("SignUpPhoneNo"))).sendKeys(prop.getProperty("PhoneNumber"));
     Thread.sleep(500);

     //Click Agree Tick
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sighUpForm']/div[6]/label/input")).click(); 
     Thread.sleep(600);

     //Click Submit button
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='submitSignup']/span")).click();
```

**Popup image :-**

[image]

Comment: Do you want to click on sign up button which presents on popup??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until element visible and clickable.

You can submit your form here in the following two ways :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
```

- You can use `.submit()` to submit the form as :-

  ```
  WebElement form = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("sighUpForm")));
  form.submit();
  ```
- You can use `.click()` to click on sign up button to submit the form as :-

  ```
  WebElement signUp = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("submitSignup")));
  signUp.click();
  ```

**Edited**:- It might be possible there are multiple `signUp` button with id `submitSignup` and unfortunately you'r interacting with hidden button, you should try to find all element with the id `signUp` and click on visible one as below :-

```
List<WebElement> signUpButtons = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.id("submitSignup")));
for(WebElement signUp : signUpButtons)
{
  if(signUp.isDisplayed() && signUp.isEnabled())
  {
    signUp.click();
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean didn't work?? is there same exception on both case or something else?

Comment: when i enter click error :- org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.id: submitSignup
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:03:33'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-PC1SJR4', ip: '192.168.0.105', os.name: 'Windows 10',

Comment: Then what happened??

Comment: but Submit runs without error but not functioning submit button

Comment: Ok, could you tell when this signUp button getting visible and clickable manually??

Comment: and also make sure locator is unique, means goto browser console by pressing f12 at that page and execute this `document.querySelectorAll("#submitSignup")` and let me know the result..

Comment: @WarunaGunaratne Or try to find all signUp button and click on visible one, try with edited answer and let me know..:)

Comment: SignUp button also in "id="sighUpForm" Form not in frame. I can't understand "document.querySelectorAll("#submitSignup")" how to add.

Comment: @WarunaGunaratne leave it, and just try with edited answer and let me know..:)

Answer (score 0):

Try with a `WebDriverWait` driver and `ExpectedCondition` of `elementToBeClickable(By locator)` on the 'Sign Up' link. This will check if element is visible and clickable.